# How to tell which parent instantiated a React component in debugger?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, components

I have an exception thrown within a component in React. This component is used by several parents in different parts of the app.

In the console, how do I tell which parent instantiated this component? eg. if I have a debugger on the line of the exception.

Comment: You could try using Error Boundary components from React. You can read more about them here: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html